# shell script to generate a map

Tags: shell, dictionary

I'd like to have a script (bash) to generate an img (gif, jpg, etc.) of a (openstreetmap or googlemap) map given a location, like this:

```
$ genmap.sh 45.5 9.5
```

(parameters are lat & long)

or:

```
$ genmap.sh 45.5 9.5 12
```

(parameters are lat & long and zoom)

etc. etc.

can you point me to something on the net?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenStreetMap has an exporting API, which you could use with, say, wget:

http://tile.openstreetmap.org/cgi-bin/export?bbox=-3.296,58.906,-2.781,59.139&scale=435000&format=png

Currently though, it gives over-load errors.

Comment: thanks, I was just making experiments with OSM urls but I missed this one :)

Answer (score 2):

Google Maps provides an API you can use for generating maps. See their documentation on the [API for static maps](http://code.google.com/intl/nl/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/).

- [Latitudes and Longitudes](http://code.google.com/intl/nl/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Latlons)
- [Zoom Levels](http://code.google.com/intl/nl/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Zoomlevels)

A basic example script which accept lat as first, long as second and an optional zoom as third. It outputs an PNG image with a filename like `lat-long-zoom-width-height.png` and echo's the filename:

```
#!/bin/bash
width=400
height=400
lat="$1"
long="$2"
zoom=12
if [ -n "$3" ]; then
    zoom="$3"
fi
filename="$lat-$long-$zoom-${width}x$height.png"
wget "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=$lat,$long&zoom=$zoom&size=${width}x${height}&sensor=false" -O "$filename"
# small error checking
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "An error occured" >&2
    exit 1
fi
echo "$filename"
```

You might need to add additional tweaks to check the error response.

Comment: both answers are complete, I'm voting OSM just because of its openness ;)